# How i can create and edit Function App using NET 7 in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I'm already deployed Function App on Azure portal. But i can't create and edit an Azure Functions with NET 7 in Visual studio 2022 v17.4 (supported NET 7).

How i  can create and edit Function App using NET 7 in Visual studio? Thanks all!

[image: Here is my tried]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run .NET 7 on Azure Functions, use .NET 6.0 Isolated. You will need both .NET 7 SDK, and .NET 6 SDK for builds.

REFs:

- [Azure Functions .NET 7 Announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/announcing-the-net-7-for-azure-functions-isolated-worker-process/ba-p/3671398#:%7E:text=Azure%20Functions%20is%20starting%20to%20roll%20out%20the,plan%2C%20Elastic%20Premium%20plan%2C%20and%20App%20Service%20plans.)

> Azure Functions is starting to roll out the RTM version of .NET 7.0 across the global infrastructure. Azure Functions will support .NET 7 serverless apps hosted on all Windows and Linux SKUs, including Consumption plan, Elastic Premium plan, and App Service plans.

> Customers can start to test in limited cloud regions (e.g West Central
> US, France Central) by the end of today. (11/8/2022)

- [Create your first C# Functions App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tabs=isolated-process)

> When you choose .NET 6 Isolated, you create a project that runs in a separate worker process. Choose isolated worker process when you need to run your function app on .NET 7.0 or on .NET Framework 4.8 (preview). To learn more, see Supported versions.

- [Supported Versions]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions

> Build process also requires .NET 6 SDK. Support for .NET Framework 4.8 is in GA.